# Can We recite any other durood in place of durood Ibrahimi in our salah?

Tags: salat

Assalamu Alaikum,

Can We recite any other durood in place of durood Ibrahimi in our salah? There are many duroods which have higher rewards than durood Ibrahimi and I want to replace durood Ibrahimi with any one of them. Or it is obligatory to recite durood Ibrahimi?

Thanks

Comment: How do you know that Other duroods have higher reward than Durrod-e-Ibrahimi?

Comment: You can find at: http://www.islamicacademy.org/html/Dorood.htm.

Comment: If you have any evidence that this durood is sourced to be said by our Prophet than go ahead. If you believe it has a source in hadith you can go ahead. If not what you will do is bida'ah. And in prayer the best to perform is what we have been taught by our Prophet and this is durood Ibrahmi. And as far as I know nobody knew or used any other in the time of the sahaba.

Answer (score 2):

All Durood Sharif are considered equal by the ulema; however, **no Durood Sharif can be better than that taught by the Prophet SallAllahu alayHi wa AaliHi waSallam Himself**; simply because it is taught by the PROPHET HIMSELF, SallAllahu alayHi wa AaliHi waSallam, whereas other formulas - although highly honorable and beneficial - are taught and derived long time after him by those lesser than the Prophet SallAllahu alayHi wa AaliHi waSallam. **The Words taught by the Prophet SallAllahu alayHi wa AaliHi waSallam are in fact Wahi from Allah**.

Not to mention, SUNNAH is better than anything, and darood e ibrahimi is what we have been taught to recite in tashud.

For reference:

> حَدَّثَنَا قَيْسُ بْنُ حَفْصٍ، وَمُوسَى بْنُ إِسْمَاعِيلَ، قَالاَ
>   حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ الْوَاحِدِ بْنُ زِيَادٍ، حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو قُرَّةَ،
>   مُسْلِمُ بْنُ سَالِمٍ الْهَمْدَانِيُّ قَالَ حَدَّثَنِي عَبْدُ اللَّهِ
>   بْنُ عِيسَى، سَمِعَ عَبْدَ الرَّحْمَنِ بْنَ أَبِي لَيْلَى، قَالَ
>   لَقِيَنِي كَعْبُ بْنُ عُجْرَةَ فَقَالَ أَلاَ أُهْدِي لَكَ هَدِيَّةً
>   سَمِعْتُهَا مِنَ النَّبِيِّ، صلى الله عليه وسلم فَقُلْتُ بَلَى،
>   فَأَهْدِهَا لِي‏.‏ فَقَالَ سَأَلْنَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه
>   وسلم فَقُلْنَا يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ كَيْفَ الصَّلاَةُ عَلَيْكُمْ أَهْلَ
>   الْبَيْتِ فَإِنَّ اللَّهَ قَدْ عَلَّمَنَا كَيْفَ نُسَلِّمُ‏.‏ قَالَ ‏
>   "‏ قُولُوا اللَّهُمَّ صَلِّ عَلَى مُحَمَّدٍ، وَعَلَى آلِ مُحَمَّدٍ،
>   كَمَا صَلَّيْتَ عَلَى إِبْرَاهِيمَ وَعَلَى آلِ إِبْرَاهِيمَ، إِنَّكَ
>   حَمِيدٌ مَجِيدٌ، اللَّهُمَّ بَارِكْ عَلَى مُحَمَّدٍ، وَعَلَى آلِ
>   مُحَمَّدٍ، كَمَا بَارَكْتَ عَلَى إِبْرَاهِيمَ، وَعَلَى آلِ
>   إِبْرَاهِيمَ، إِنَّكَ حَمِيدٌ مَجِيدٌ ‏"‏‏.‏
>
> Narrated `Abdur-Rahman bin Abi Laila:
>
> Ka'b bin Ujrah met me and said, "Shall I not give you a present I got
>   from the Prophet?" `Abdur- Rahman said, "Yes, give it to me." I said,
>   "We asked Allah's Apostle saying, 'O Allah's Apostle! How should one
>   (ask Allah to) send blessings on you, the members of the family, for
>   Allah has taught us how to salute you (in the prayer)?' He said, 'Say:
>   O Allah! Send Your Mercy on Muhammad and on the family of Muhammad, as
>   You sent Your Mercy on Abraham and on the family of Abraham, for You
>   are the Most Praise-worthy, the Most Glorious. O Allah! Send Your
>   Blessings on Muhammad and the family of Muhammad, as You sent your
>   Blessings on Abraham and on the family of Abraham, for You are the
>   Most Praise-worthy, the Most Glorious.' "
>
> Reference: Sahih al-Bukhari 3370 In-book reference: Book 60, Hadith 49
>   English translation: Vol. 4, Book 55, Hadith 589

And a very famous hadees:

> صلوا کما رایتمونی اصلی - “**Pray as you see me praying.**”

So please correct your understanding: Durood e Ibrahimi is considered "Ummus-Salawat", the 'Mother of All Duroods'. It is what holy prophet recited in his prayer, and muslims believe he is the perfect man and no one can be ebtter than him.